# Using networkd, how to see DNS Server

Tags: netplan

So the Ubuntu server is configured with netplan and the renderer is: networkd.

How does one see the active DNS Server ? i.e. there is no NetworkManager.

Comment: `netplan` is the default?  How do you know that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using netplan (17.10 Artful Ardvark on) and the renderer is: 
*networkd*, there is no *NetworkManager* so the *nmcli* commands do not apply. The cat */etc/resolv.conf* simply shows the nameserver to be *127.0.0.53*, not very helpful really ;-)

To get the nameservers.

```
ubuntu@ub-17-10:~$ systemd-resolve --status | sed -n '/DNS Servers/,/^$/p'
         DNS Servers: 192.168.92.201
                      8.8.8.8
          DNS Domain: netlabsug.tst
```

Comment: is `127.0.0.53`, as a name server, a bug?  https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7009

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use

```
netplan ip leases eno1
```

where `eno1` is your interface name.

```
# This is private data. Do not parse.
ADDRESS=192.168.a.b
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ROUTER=192.168.a.d
SERVER_ADDRESS=192.168.a.d
NEXT_SERVER=192.168.a.d
T1=10800
T2=18900
LIFETIME=21600
DNS=192.168.a.d
NTP=192.168.a.d
CLIENTID=...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can type this if netplan is used :

```
$ netplan get | sed -n '/nameservers:/,$ p'
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - X.Y.Z.T
        search:
        - myLAN.lan
      gateway4: A.B.C.D
```